# "Error message showing" best practice for C++ windows application

Tags: c++, winforms, user-interface, user-experience

Showing error messages in windows application can do in several ways.

1. Default error message popup with `OK` button.
2. Custom dialog with error message (may be with `cancel` and `ok` buttons)
3. Showing some place in the window while other elements are active.
4. Mask the window by transparent panel and show error on that with `ok` button (something like [this](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-nDDrm68P10g/TV9EHBozRnI/AAAAAAAAAP8/RZX5jWSyHQI/s1600/Form.jpg), but not exactly).

So which method most suitable for error message display. And what are the things we have to consider showing error messages to user or any best practices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the severity of the error.
If you have a wrong input into a `Textfield`, you might show a label with red letters displaying "error" or something similar.
For more severe errors you might display a `MessageBox` with a nice white cross on red ground indicating something has really gone wrong.
Consider that for just minor input-errors popups might distract the user or even irritate him/her.

Comment: But some says popup message is like disturbing user experience and the them of the UI, so  better to show error in a label on the window. Any idea?

Comment: This depends on the case. If you have a very severe error, you need to inform the user about it. Otherwise just use a label or simple popup that is not a modal dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

Most languages give you an option to make the message style error. The accepted practice appears to be an okay button only with an error message "style". Usually this means that the the icon is an exclamation point or something similar.